# How to construct Spring's dependency graph without refreshing the context?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-ide

Is there any way to construct Spring's bean dependency graph without doing refresh() to a context? By using the BeanDefinitions gathered by the Spring Readers or so

I want to build the dependency graph for an application with the minimum waste of memory/time.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Java IDEs have support to draw spring dependency graph either innately or via plug-ins.

- In eclipse, with Spring Source Tool Suite installed, you could view dependency graph by selecting spring configuration (xml) files in Spring Explorer view and right-clicking and selecting "Open dependency graph".
- In IntelliJ IDEA, you could view it by right clicking the configuration files and selecting Diagrams -> Show Diagram.

Comment: I know that options. But what I want to do is build the graph programatically (so far I've tried to do it with Spring code, but for gathering all the information it requires me to get a context up) so I can query it.

Comment: Why don't you look at Spring Source Tool suite source code then?

Comment: I could but dig into the code of a open source tool to find a quite theoretical question about Spring sounds like an overkill.